# Duplicate INSERT record procedure

Tags: plsql, insert, duplicates, procedure

I have problem with mu procedure which insert duplicate last record in table

example when I put INSERT..... 'AAA' I got to rows in table 'AAA' and 'AAA'

In place when I put DBMS()... in code I got tow records
I use trigger and sequence for column ID in HistoriaDismissDate but they are in good condition. I check if I dropped trigger and sequence and its the same situation

I also use viewDate but this view get mi ONE record not two

my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ChangeDismissDate
IS

          v_id VARCHAR2(11);
          v_dateBhd DATE := TO_DATE('20491231','yyyymmdd');
          v_dateDismiss DATE := TO_DATE('20491231','yyyymmdd');
          v_login VARCHAR2(50);
          last_id NUMBER :=0;

        CURSOR cur IS
                select EMP_NO, LOGIN, ODEJSCIE_BHD, ODEJSCIE_OLD FROM viewDate;

        BEGIN
                       OPEN cur;
                           LOOP
                                FETCH cur INTO v_id,v_login,v_dateBhd,v_dateDismiss;
                                  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_id || ' ' || v_login || ' ' || v_dateBhd || ' ' || v_dateDismiss);
                                 UPDATE employee_tab SET DISMISS_DATE = v_dateBhd WHERE EMP_NO = v_id;
                                 COMMIT;

                                 INSERT INTO HistoriaDismissDate(CUSTOMER_ID,LOGIN, DATE_CHANGE, DATE_BHD, DATE_DISMISS)
                                 VALUES(v_id,v_login, sysdate, v_dateBhd, v_dateDismiss);
                                 COMMIT;

                           EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
                           END LOOP;
                           CLOSE cur;


    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack);
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack);
    END;
/
```

Comment: put `EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;` right after `FETCH cur INTO `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 tips on your original code:

1) cursor is a **very** old programming technic on PL/SQL. Prefer to use FOR ... LOOP construction. It's cleaner and less error-prone! See how it works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ChangeDismissDate IS
BEGIN
  for cur in (select EMP_NO, LOGIN, ODEJSCIE_BHD, ODEJSCIE_OLD FROM viewDate) loop

     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(cur.EMP_NO || ' ' || cur.login || ' ' || cur.ODEJSCIE_BHD || ' ' || cur.ODEJSCIE_OLD);
     UPDATE employee_tab 
        SET DISMISS_DATE = cur.ODEJSCIE_BHD
      WHERE EMP_NO = cur.EMP_NO;

     INSERT INTO HistoriaDismissDate
       ( CUSTOMER_ID,LOGIN, DATE_CHANGE, DATE_BHD, DATE_DISMISS )
     VALUES
       ( cur.EMP_NO, cur.LOGIN, sysdate, cur.ODEJSCIE_BHD, cur.ODEJSCIE_OLD, );
  end loop;
end;
/
```

2) **Never**, I mean never put a commit inside your procedure. The commit should be done on the caller block or on your client-side app. When you put a commit inside your procedure, you miss the chance to rollback after running it and other procedures could not call it if they want to control the transaction flow.